# Pdf.js: print rendering in Safari & Chrome

Tags: tcpdf, pdf.js, fpdi

I am generating a PDF using TCPDF and feeding the resulting base64 stream to pdf.js for printing. The display output appears as expected, but when I preview or print the document, some unexpected scaling takes place.

In TCPDF, I am importing an existing PDF and overlaying that with data that is generated on the fly. The imported PDF in the print output is being scaled to about 25% of the page while the dynamic data appears to be scaled properly.

Display output - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPQPt.png
Print output - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go1Wy.png

This happens in Safari and Chrome, but in Firefox the print output is rendered correctly.

Any advice on how to get Safari and Chrome to cooperate?

Comment: Using pdf.js in SVG "mode" will be a better choice for the browsers that do not have mozPrintCallback.

Comment: Is there a config option for printing in SVG mode? The documentation I've looked at doesn't indicate this ability.